# Problem with updating object property in array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm making an ecommrece project, in search bar I'm displaying checkboxes with categories from the API, all of those have value active == true by default. This is how I'm mapping them:

```
{categories.map((category) => {
       return (
              <>
             <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => handleCheckbox(category)} 
             defaultChecked={category.active} key={category.name} />
             <label style={{marginLeft:"5px"}} htmlFor={category.name}>{category.name}</label><br/>
             </> 
)
})}
```

Then I run this function to change category.active property from true to false, when the exact checkbox is clicked, then I want to update this object using useState

```
const handleCheckbox = (category) => {
    let tempCategory = category
    if (tempCategory.active == true) {
        tempCategory.active = false;
    } else {
        tempCategory.active = true;
    }
    setCategories({...categories, [tempCategory.id]: tempCategory})
    console.log(category.active)
}
```

Unfortunetly when I click on the checkbox I'm getting an error from React:

```
TypeError: categories.map is not a function
```

And it points to categories.map, I have no idea how to fix it. All I want is to update specific object in the `categories` array.

Comment: We seem to be missing the bit where categories is created.

Comment: When you click handleCheckbox you set categories to an object, so either categories are not an array and you should try doing `Object.values(categories).map()`, or change the setCategories to set it to an actual array

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I changed setCategories to `setCategories([...categories, tempCategory])` and it works, but now everytime I click on the checkbox in appends another object instead of updating an existing one

Comment: then maybe make it into an object instead, and leave the setter as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your categories start life as an array of category objects, and you meant to `setCategories` to an array - but instead you're setting it to an object.

You also need to make sure you dont double up `tempCategory`. something like this:

```
setCategories([
 ...categories.filter(x => x.id != tempCategory.id), 
 tempCategory
]);
```

However, this will reorder your categories, putting `tempCategory` at the end, so another option is to slice the array correctly

```
const tmpIdx = categories.findIndex(x => x.id == tempCategory.id);
setCategories([
     ...categories.slice(0,tmpIdx), 
     tempCategory,
     ...categories.slice(tmpIdx+1), 
]);
```

Another option is make your `categories` an object and use `Object.values(categories).map(...)` but this makes ordering your categories harder, as there is no fixed ordering of object keys/values like there is with an array.

Comment: It works, by when I click on the ckeckbox it changes it's place to the last one in form, FE:
(X) Category 1
(X) Category 2
(X) Category 3
And I when uncheck Category 2 it goes like:
(X) Category 1
(X) Category 3
(O) Category 2
I hope you understand. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @mateuszlaczynski you might be missing the update to this answer made before that comment. refresh the page

Comment: @mateuszlaczynski subtle bug - I used `splice` and i meant to use `slice`! Now updated

Comment: It works perfectly fine. Thanks you made my day! :)

Comment: Glad I could help, sorry for the confusing original answer :)